# Display thumbnails to choose video from external storage using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, video

In one of the activities, I am displaying the list of videos by implementing `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` . This works well to let the user select the video from the list of titles. I thought of displaying thumbnails along with title. But, I could not find a good example. Since this should be a common task, I thought of doing it the *standard way,* but I see no straightforward way to achieve this from the google search results I did.

```
private static final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;


public String[] fromColumns = {
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE
};
public int[] mToFields = {
        android.R.id.text1
};
```

and in onCreate():

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.video_list);

adapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,                // Current context
                android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,  // Layout for a single row
                null,                // No Cursor yet
                fromColumns,        // Cursor columns to use
                mToFields,           // Layout fields to use
                0                    // No flags
        );
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is onCreateLoader(). I can modify this as required.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {
/*
 * Takes action based on the ID of the Loader that's being created
 */
    switch (loaderID) {
        case URL_LOADER:
            // Returns a new CursorLoader
            return new CursorLoader(
                    this,   // Parent activity context
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,     // Projection to return
                    null,            // No selection clause
                    null,            // No selection arguments
                    null             // Default sort order
            );
        default:
            // An invalid id was passed in
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is content of your `Cursor`? dump at least one row

Comment: pskink: Updated the question with details of onCreateLoader(). Would that help. I think I have only the TITLE information as of now, but I can add more columns to fromColumns if needed.

Comment: so you have `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails` to query and get two kinds of thumbnails: MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96 thumbnail

Comment: Sorry if this sounds too naive. Would you point to some sample code as I am not sure how to connect things? Thanks.

Comment: Would you suggest to extend SimpleCursorAdapter and then return an imageView on getView using MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails ?

Comment: you can either extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override its `setViewImage` or setup the `ViewBinder`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will learn about ViewBinder and then choose one of the options.